# How do I solve Xcode's "This app could not be installed at this time." error

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, simulator

Sometimes, Xcode will not install Apps in the simulator, giving nothing more than the message "This app could not be installed at this time.".

Answer (score 2):

The simulator writes a log for the events that occur while installing an App.

To access it, list the available simulators by typing this in the terminal:

```
instruments -s devices
```

this will give you a list with entries like

```
iPad Pro (10.5-inch) (11.4) [75DE3247-4641-4D71-BAC1-3EC3B019FC87] (Simulator)
```

Copy the uuid between the brackets for the simulator you are using.

Then type

```
cd ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<THE-UUID-YOU-JUST-COPIED>/MobileInstallation
```

You are now in a directory, that contains the installation logs.
Open the newest log and look for errors of your installation (most likely at the end of the log).

Answer (score 0):

First Reset the simulator by following option:

**Hardware -> Erase All content and settings...**

and then clean your project by following commands:

**shift+cmd+K**

**shift+opt+cmd+K**

If you still want to know what exactly causing the issue, you can check at log files from below location:

> *~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*